# Cannot access PDF doc pages/events from iTextSharp with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pdf, itext, livecycle

Ideally, I am trying to trigger an event in a PDF, using iTextSharp.
Failing that, I would like to know if I can trigger a function.

Basically, I'm just trying to get a handle of the document through javascript.

This works in the PDF

(Using LiveCycle):

```
eApp.Page1.FormPurpose_PolicyNumber::click -
```

(JavaScript, client)

```
this.rawValue = "hello";
```

From C# I can't get a handle on the doc, `eApp` in this case.

```
var reader = new PdfReader(pdfFileStream);
var writer = new PdfStamper(reader, outputStream);
```

THIS WORKS:(app object)

```
PdfAction js =
    PdfAction.JavaScript(
        "app.alert('hello');",
        writer.Writer);

writer.Writer.AddJavaScript(js);
```

THIS DOES NOT:

```
PdfAction js =
    PdfAction.JavaScript(
        "eApp.Page1.FormPurpose_PolicyNumber.execEvent('click');",
        writer.Writer);

writer.Writer.AddJavaScript(js);
```

Also doesn't work:

```
PdfAction js =
    PdfAction.JavaScript(
        "eApp.Page1.FormPurpose_PolicyNumber.rawValue= 'hello'",
        writer.Writer);

writer.Writer.AddJavaScript(js);
```

I have looked for the answer high and low, but have not been able to find it, yes there are similar questions, but either they are not answered or are very different than what I'm doing.

Comment: [JS API](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf) - have you checked this? Frankly speaking it's not clear to me what you want to get in result.

Comment: I'm trying to send javascript using C# and iTextSharp, so that it can trigger an event or function existing in the PDF.
None of the events on the PDF are triggering, so looking for a way to trigger them.

Comment: There is document start event or something like that. Which is triggered when someone open a PDF. Supose you can post your code there. See this [post](http://mattheyan.blogspot.com/2010/06/add-javascript-to-pdf-document-with.html) which may be helpful for you. Shortly - guy starts printing when document is opened.

Comment: Besides, you can try to add javascript you need with Adobe Acroba (trial?) and check in its debugger what is going on there. Also it is not clear to me what is eApp in your js code? it sounds to me like something that is not available in Adobe PDF JS

Comment: What I'm trying to do is access my document in this case called eApp and trigger an event or function.
The problem that im having is that im flattening the file by using:
write.FormFlattening = true;

so the resulting form wont execute any scripts inside of it, so I am trying to execute it, through javascript before i flatten it.

Just need to get a handle on it like:

PdfAction js =
    PdfAction.JavaScript(
        "eApp.Page1.FormPurpose_PolicyNumber.execEvent('click');",
        writer.Writer);

The name of the object inside livecycle is xfa.form.eApp.page1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your latest comment - that won't work. iTextSharp will only add some scripts into a document. And that script will be started in some client app, like Adobe Reader. It will not execte any scripts inside of your document. Suppose in your case it will be easier to do whatewer you want with document using c# and than save it with form flattening set to true.

Comment: Ah thanks, yea that might be what I'll end up doing.
Appreciate the input.

Comment: @CesarHerrera just realized that the other possible solution is to flatten your document with javascript. So people will open it, your JS will start and do what you need. After that you may flatten your document. As I can see there is some similar function in JS API

Comment: Ah thanks, I tried to do something like this, but only thing I found was the .access property, for example, eApp.access = "protected" but that is not the same as flattening, is there a flatten command?

Its ok if there isnt though, we might just do things in c# then flatten.

Comment: See Doc.flattenPages in JS API Refference. Suppose that is the same as flatten in C#

Comment: Yea, sadly that doesnt work on Livecycle. At least from all I've read it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case working solution is:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(this.pathToPDFTemplate);
...
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, stream);
...
PdfAction action = PdfAction.JavaScript("this.xfa.form.form1.DesignArea.sfPart3.sfPart3_5.ck2.presence = 'hidden';", stamper.Writer);
stamper.Writer.SetAdditionalAction(PdfWriter.WILL_PRINT, action);
...
```

The trick is to use this.xfa.form. before your path to the field.